# Accessing a variable passed in a url in python bs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a website and have come across an issue I can not figure out.

I have extracted the following data from the site:

````
```
   tmp = ['/gourl/2aae9bb244631cf75ac56f4f61384c2dcda0d0e9?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F234343435'] 
```
````

How can I save the results of ?redirect.

I have tried this:

````
    ```
link = re.search("?redirect=", tmp)
    ```
````

and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# python3

import urllib.parse

tmp = [
    "/gourl/2aae9bb244631cf75ac56f4f61384c2dcda0d0e9?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F234343435"
]

for el in tmp:
    url = el.split("?redirect=")[1]
    url_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(url)
    print(url_decoded)
```

Result:
`http://www.facebook.com/234343435`

Comment: Words perfectly. Thank you.