# selenium firefox driver no results returned

Tags: python, selenium

I am using VSC Editor, Windows 10, the latest version of Python and all associated plugins.
The browser I am using is FireFox (latest version as well).

When I run my code, a headless browser appears and I can see that my search criteria is entered in to the text box, the search button hit and the results are displayed in the browser.

However, in my code, when I print out the results, I get an empty list [].

What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
 
search_form = driver.find_element_by_id("search_form_input_homepage")
search_form.clear()
search_form.send_keys("python jobs remote")
search_form.submit()

results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result")
print(results[0])
driver.close()
```

Comment: @Prophet : thnx, I checked it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298286/accessing-a-variable-passed-in-a-url-in-python-bs

Comment: you probably need a webdriverwait here.  (or a sleep... expected conditions for findall elements will only wait until at least 1 element is found... need a sleep or check for stale element exceptions and re-call )